# Interactive proof for PSPACE-hard problems different from QBF

Tags: complexity-theory, interactive-proof-systems

The celebrated proof that [IP = PSPACE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_(complexity)) relies on an interactive proof for the [QBF problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_quantified_Boolean_formula).

Is there any other "natural" interactive proof for a PSPACE-hard problem other than QBF?

(of course, since QBF is PSPACE-complete, such a proof exists via a reduction to QBF; I ask for a direct interactive proof that does *not* go through the reduction).